# Why is int *arr = new int [number] used in this case?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++. I had seen one sample code as shown below:

```
int quantity;
cout << "Enter the number of items: " << endl;
cin >> quantity;
int *arr = new int[quantity];

for(int i=0; i <quantity; i++)
{ 
cout<< "Enter item no." << i << endl;
cin >> arr[i];
}
```

But when I replaced the `int *arr = new int[quantity];` with `int arr[quantity];`, the program can still be compiled without any error messages. Why is `int *arr = new int[quantity]` used instead of `int arr[quantity]`?

Comment: You are building with extensions. Standard C++ doesn't allow the change you made.

Comment: Note that the _usual_ way to write this is `std::vector<int> arr(quantity)`.

Comment: If you use `new`, don’t forget to `delete`.

Comment: Off-topic but these `cout` and `cin` mean you have a `using namespace std;` somewhere which [you should probably avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: _I had seen one sample code_ it's bad code, don't learn from it. Use std::vector!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quantity` is not a compile-time constant, so the following:

```
int arr[quantity];
```

...is not valid C++ (even though it is valid C99).

Your code probably compiles because your compiler as an extension allowing this construct, such as [GCC VLA extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html):

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an **extension** GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++.

Compiling with `-pedantic` should give you at least a warning. GCC gives me the following (with `-pedantic`):

> 8 : :8:21: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla]
>
> ```
> int arr[quantity];
> ```

Note that in this case, you should probably be using a `std::vector` and not a manually allocated array:

```
std::vector<int> arr(quantity);
```